# Chef Server Migration

Tags: chef, migration, open-source

A company that I'm contracting with has determined that they need to migrate their Chef (Open-Source Edition) instance to a new server.

They do not want to migrate to the Hosted platform.

I have not been able to find a guide for how to do this.  Does anyone have guidance or experiences to share, or better yet, a Guide?

---

I have steps in mind for doing this, but I'm afraid that I'm going to miss something vital.  Sadly, their Chef-Server is not managed via Chef...

Comment: Are they just moving to different (new) hardware?  Can you just make a system backup, and then restore?

Comment: They are going to new hardware.  I actually hadn't considered a backup/restore... Perhaps I'm overthinking the problem...?

Comment: You'll have to decide if you are over-thinking.  But if your goal is just to move to better/different hardware, then a backup/restore should be simple, and painless.  There are several questions/answers on the site that describe how to move Linux to new hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a short guide on OpsCode wiki which talks about it.

> http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Backing+Up+Chef+Server

The CouchDB backup and restore is more preferred, as also backup and restores the validation.pem, webui.pem, etc.

Like all backup and recovery tasks, do a dry run before a final switch over.

Comment: The link is dead. Information for the latest Chef Server version can be found [here](https://docs.chef.io/release/server_12-8/server_backup_restore.html)

Answer (score 3):

For Chef Server 11, [they switched from CouchDB to Postgres](http://www.getchef.com/blog/2013/02/15/the-making-of-erchef-the-chef-11-server/) which rules out couchdump. chef_server_backup.rb has also [been abandoned](https://github.com/jtimberman/knife-scripts#chef_server_backuprb), but [knife-backup](https://github.com/mdxp/knife-backup) can handle both 10 and 11.

If on both systems you have [knife-backup](https://github.com/mdxp/knife-backup) installed and a knife user setup, you can

> originalserver$ knife backup export -D ~/chef-backup/

Copy over ~/chef-backup/ to the new hosts and

> newserver$ knife backup restore -D ~/chef-backup

Make sure to read the stipulations on [knife-backup](https://github.com/mdxp/knife-backup). Alternatively, you can also push it with [multiple knife profiles](http://www.ameir.net/blog/archives/326-migrating-from-one-chef-server-to-another.html). Also note when installing, if you're using knife from an omnibus package make sure to call the right instance of gem (/opt/chef(-server)?/embedded/bin/gem).